# OpenCV matrix weird behavior of addition, multiplication with float point and 8bit value

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using OpenCV version 3.4.5. I tried to understand the behavior of `cv::Mat` in OpenCV. I multiple some 8bit matrices and add them up. The result seems inconsistent.

Does OpenCV cast the float point result immediately back to 8bit after each multiplication, or after each addition, or maybe some "Fused Multiply Add" happened here ?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main() {
    for (int value = 1; value < 10; value++) {
        cv::Mat im(1, 1, CV_8U, value);
        cv::Mat result[10];
        result[0] = im*0.1f;
        result[1] = im*0.1f + im*0.1f;
        result[2] = im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f;
        result[3] = im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f;
        result[4] = im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f;
        result[5] = im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f;
        result[6] = im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f;
        result[7] = im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f;
        result[8] = im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f;
        result[9] = im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f;
        std::cout << "base value: " << value << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            std::cout << i + 1 << ": " << int(result[i].at<uint8_t>(0, 0)) << "\t";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The outputs are:

```
base value: 1
1: 0    2: 0    3: 0    4: 0    5: 0    6: 0    7: 0    8: 0    9: 0    10: 0
base value: 2
1: 0    2: 0    3: 0    4: 0    5: 0    6: 0    7: 0    8: 0    9: 0    10: 0
base value: 3
1: 0    2: 1    3: 1    4: 1    5: 1    6: 1    7: 1    8: 1    9: 1    10: 1
base value: 4
1: 0    2: 1    3: 1    4: 1    5: 1    6: 1    7: 1    8: 1    9: 1    10: 1
base value: 5
1: 0    2: 1    3: 2    4: 2    5: 2    6: 2    7: 2    8: 2    9: 2    10: 2
base value: 6
1: 1    2: 1    3: 2    4: 3    5: 4    6: 5    7: 6    8: 7    9: 8    10: 9
base value: 7
1: 1    2: 1    3: 2    4: 3    5: 4    6: 5    7: 6    8: 7    9: 8    10: 9
base value: 8
1: 1    2: 2    3: 3    4: 4    5: 5    6: 6    7: 7    8: 8    9: 9    10: 10
base value: 9
1: 1    2: 2    3: 3    4: 4    5: 5    6: 6    7: 7    8: 8    9: 9    10: 10
```

Comment: What is the expected result ?

Comment: If all calculations are in float point number, then 0.4 + 0.4 + 0.4 ... shouldn't be 1. Then 5*0.1 gives zero seems the rounding is towards lower integer. If all calculations are in 8bit and round to lower integer, 0.4 + 0.4 + 0.4 ... should be zero. But then 0.4+0.4=0.8 gives 1 means the rounding is towards to nearest integer. I'm confused.

Comment: `im * 0.1f` -- the data type of `im` is `CV_8U`. The multiplication won't change that, the result will again be a matrix of 8bit unsigned integers. If you want a floating point result, you first need to convert `im` to floating point, and then do the multiplication. In fact, the scaled `im` should probably go into a temporary variable, since there's no point doing the same exact multiplication of the entire mat over and over and over again...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In OpenCV, the operations between `cv::Mat` is not evaluated right away for performance reason. 
It uses delayed evaluation. If you do `A = B*0.1 + C*0.1` (`A`,`B`,`C` is `cv::Mat`), a `cv::MatExpr` that holds `B`,`C` and their scale value `0.1` and `0.1` is created. And it is evaluated only when the operations are more than 3 or assigned to an actual `cv::Mat`.

If you don't assign `B*0.1 + C*0.1` to an actual `cv::Mat`, the evaluation will not happen.

If you do `A = B*0.1 + C*0.1 + D*0.1`, a `cv::MatExpr` that holds `B*0.1` and `C*0.1`is created, and then another `cv::MatExpr` is created which holds last `cv::MatExpr`'s evaluation and `D*0.1`. This is why operations more than 3 is absurd. During *evaluation*, since the type is not floating-point, the 0.x is lost.

To avoid this problem, just set type to `CV_32F` or `CV_64F`.

Your `im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f + ...` is actually working like this.

```
result = im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f + im*0.1f +   ...
  ∧         │         │         │         │
  │      MatExpr   MatExpr   MatExpr   MatExpr     ...
  │         │         │         │         │
  │         └────┬────┘         │         │
  │           MatExpr           │         │
  │eval          │              │         │
  │              └>────────┬───<┘         │
  │              eval   MatExpr           │
  │                        │              │
  │                        └>────────┬───<┘
  │                        eval   MatExpr
  │                                 ...            ...
  │      
  │                                  └>────────┬───<┘
  │                                  eval   MatExpr
  │                                            │
  └<──────────────────────────────────────────<┘
```

### matop.cpp

#### `cv::Mat`*`double`

```
class MatOp_AddEx : public MatOp
{
public:

    void assign(const MatExpr& expr, Mat& m, int type=-1) const;
    void add(const MatExpr& e1, const Scalar& s, MatExpr& res) const;
    static void makeExpr(MatExpr& res, const Mat& a, const Mat& b, double alpha, double beta, const Scalar& s=Scalar());

    // erased others for clarity
};

static MatOp_AddEx g_MatOp_AddEx; // only visible in matop.cpp
```

```
MatExpr operator * (const Mat& a, double s)
{
    MatExpr e;
    MatOp_AddEx::makeExpr(e, a, Mat(), s, 0); // meaning a*s + NULL-mat*0
    return e;
}
```

```
inline void MatOp_AddEx::makeExpr(MatExpr& res, const Mat& a, const Mat& b, double alpha, double beta, const Scalar& s)
{
    res = MatExpr(&g_MatOp_AddEx, 0, a, b, Mat(), alpha, beta, s); // MatExpr constructor
}
```

#### `cv::MatExpr` + `cv::MatExpr`

```
MatExpr operator + (const MatExpr& e1, const MatExpr& e2)
{
    MatExpr en;
    e1.op->add(e1, e2, en); // MatOp_AddEx inherits MatOp
    return en;
}
```

```
void MatOp::add(const MatExpr& e1, const MatExpr& e2, MatExpr& res) const
{
    CV_INSTRUMENT_REGION()

    if( this == e2.op )
    {
        double alpha = 1, beta = 1;
        Scalar s;
        Mat m1, m2;
        if( isAddEx(e1) && (!e1.b.data || e1.beta == 0) )
        {
            m1 = e1.a;
            alpha = e1.alpha;
            s = e1.s;
        }
        else
            e1.op->assign(e1, m1);  // <- Evaluation. Remember that type is set to auto(-1) by default

        if( isAddEx(e2) && (!e2.b.data || e2.beta == 0) )
        {
            m2 = e2.a;
            beta = e2.alpha;
            s += e2.s;
        }
        else
            e2.op->assign(e2, m2);  // <- Evaluation
        MatOp_AddEx::makeExpr(res, m1, m2, alpha, beta, s);
    }
    else
        e2.op->add(e1, e2, res);  // <- Evaluation

}
```

```
void MatOp_AddEx::assign(const MatExpr& e, Mat& m, int _type) const
{
    Mat temp, &dst = _type == -1 || e.a.type() == _type ? m : temp;
    if( e.b.data )
    {
        if( e.s == Scalar() || !e.s.isReal() )
        {
            if( e.alpha == 1 )
            {
                if( e.beta == 1 )
                    cv::add(e.a, e.b, dst);
                else if( e.beta == -1 )
                    cv::subtract(e.a, e.b, dst);
                else
                    cv::scaleAdd(e.b, e.beta, e.a, dst);
            }
            else if( e.beta == 1 )
            {
                if( e.alpha == -1 )
                    cv::subtract(e.b, e.a, dst);
                else
                    cv::scaleAdd(e.a, e.alpha, e.b, dst);
            }
            else
                cv::addWeighted(e.a, e.alpha, e.b, e.beta, 0, dst);

            if( !e.s.isReal() )
                cv::add(dst, e.s, dst);
        }
        else
            cv::addWeighted(e.a, e.alpha, e.b, e.beta, e.s[0], dst);
    }
    else if( e.s.isReal() && (dst.data != m.data || fabs(e.alpha) != 1))
    {
        e.a.convertTo(m, _type, e.alpha, e.s[0]);
        return;
    }
    else if( e.alpha == 1 )
        cv::add(e.a, e.s, dst);
    else if( e.alpha == -1 )
        cv::subtract(e.s, e.a, dst);
    else
    {
        e.a.convertTo(dst, e.a.type(), e.alpha);
        cv::add(dst, e.s, dst);
    }

    if( dst.data != m.data )
        dst.convertTo(m, m.type());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this nice drawing! I thought there might be some lazy evalution mechanism but didn't dig into the source code. This explains all outputs except 5*0.1 gives 0. Then I realized, even though it rounds to the nearest integer, since 0.1 is not represented exactly in float point number, 5 * 0.1 should be a little bit less than 0.5, thus gives 0 after the rounding.